# How to handle different DB based on different config files for each user?

Tags: php

I'm facing a new challenge at work and, as happens to me with all challenges, I'm a bit excited but I stucked a little bit at planning.

We have a CRM solution we are planning to sell to other companies within our servers. That said, I thought that, to avoid having a overpopulated database, we should have separated databases for each company that sign up in the application.

So, every company would have a subdomain like mycompanie.mywonderfullcrm.com and so, that URL points to a folder that should be something like \root_folder\clients\mycompanie\ and within that, it **only** would be the "config" file which then points to the correct database.

From my point of view, that allows to update easily the tool to fix bugs or add new features.

My question is... how could I use core application files with different config files in different folders?

Comment: Generally I structure my core config classes to accept an array of values and then separate the logic of where to actually get that array into the bootstrapper class. This way config file names aren't tightly coupled to the core code and it's a simple matter of assigning an environment constant early on in the boot process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the php system variable $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to determine to wich company the http client is refering. then you could load the config file from your folder. here a short untested example:

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);  
$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);  
$subdomain = $host[0]; 

/* include config here */
include_once('\root_folder\clients\'.$subdomain.'\config.php');
```

Comment: Note that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` can be tampered with, so if your code relies on it you could get unexpected results.